# Limitation for data-set (items) with Highstock/Highcharts?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am using Highcharts for rendering a bunch of data, but with more than 200 datasets nothing gets displayed. Is there a limit of items? In my case I have several thousand entries, e.g. 20000.

Are there any alternatives to Highstock/Highcharts, which can handle big data??

Best Regards

Comment: have you tried the highcharts forum?  I've posted bugs and questions before, the devs are fairly responsive.  http://highslide.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=8

Comment: Do you mean 200 individual series or 200 data points in a series? If the former my first question is "do you expect the user to get any info out of a chart with 200 series"? If the later then there is no upper limit but it may be slower than desired.

Comment: @wergeld I have one serie with 10.000 data-points. I have a lot of data to visualize (performance-test data). The scatter and/or the column charts are nice for that. The x-axis is a datetime-timeline

Comment: @raoulinski That makes more sense =). I can't imagine plotting 200 series at once would provide anything useful. tuborThreashold is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Tom. I found an answer in the Forum. http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=17019&p=72268#p72268

I followed the information about the **turboThreshold**, http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#plotOptions-series--turboThreshold
It says: *When a series contains a data array that is longer than this, only one dimensional arrays of numbers, or two dimensional arrays with x and y values are allowed. Also, only the first point is tested, and the rest are assumed to be the same format. This saves expensive data checking and indexing in long series. Defaults to 1000.*

Either I could increase the turboThreshold to the amount of data, e.g. 10.000 - or I could use a one or two-dimensional array for the data (before I used an object). Then it works.

Comment: I think setting turboThreshold to 0 disables it and then you can virtually have any number of points :)